# Display autocomplete list into a angularjs modal directive, list is ok but display not

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-directive, jquery-ui-autocomplete, angular-ui

I expect to display jquery autocomplete list into a angularjs modal within a directive.
I handle to display the list but it is displayed behind the modal.

[See demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/A8tOOY?p=preview)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is not an angularjs problem.

Set a value to the z-index property of your suggest list (must be greater than the z-index property of your modal):

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    z-index: 1051; /* z-index of modal is equal to 1050. */
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's perfect. I did not know about this z-index :)

Answer (score 0):

set the value of z-index in the src/style.css in your angular project to overview the value

```
.cdk-overlay-container{
     z-index: 1050 !important;
}
```